# What's wrong with a TLS based VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

The recent US DoD Advisory on *Hardening Remote Access VPNs* recommends the following:

> Avoid selecting non-standard VPN solutions, including a class of products
> referred to as Secure Sockets Layer/Transport Layer Security (SSL/TLS) VPNs.
> These products include custom, non-standard features to tunnel traffic via TLS

Read here:
https://media.defense.gov/2021/Sep/28/2002863184/-1/-1/0/CSI_SELECTING-HARDENING-REMOTE-ACCESS-VPNS-20210928.PDF

Apart from the possible performance bottlenecks by using a Transport layer VPN, what exactly are other security concerns ? (assuming TLS v1.3 is used)

> Using custom or non-standard features creates additional risk exposure, even
> when the TLS parameters used by the products are secure.

How ?, or Why ?